# Conditionally Editing Multiple Columns of a Vector Simultaneously

Tags: matlab

So, let's say I have a vector that's <262792x4 double> in dimension. The first and second columns are necessary for organization (they represent points on a grid), and the next two columns of data are latitude and longitude respectively.

ex:

```
1   1   12.1899300000000    -133.458980000000
2   1   12.2198400000000    -133.353880000000
3   1   12.2496700000000    -133.248720000000
4   1   12.2794300000000    -133.143550000000
5   1   12.3091000000000    -133.038270000000
```

I want to conditionally get rid of rows in the column where the ranges of the latitude and longitude values do not comply.

For instance, I'd like to have a range in the third and fourth columns of (37.7462*BUT* in the event of this:

```
300 193 38.3105400000000    -101.476440000000
```

Since both column conditions for the row aren't satisfied since the 4th column is sporting a value less than -97.2339, I'd like to delete that row entirely. So I only want the rows where the conditions are met in the third and fourth column at the same time.

This is something that I thought would kind of work, but didn't (the vector is called 'NOAAlatlongdata':

```
% Lat/Long Value Box Truncation

% Upper Right Box lat/long (in decimal form )
latUR= 39.4993;
longUR= -93.2339;

%Lower Left Box Point lat/long (in decimal form)
latLL = 37.7462;
longLL = -97.3453;

%Upper Left Box Point
latUL= latLL;
longUL = longUR;

%Lower Right Box Point
latLR = latUR;
longLR = longLL;

%Latitude range in the box is going to go from latLL to latUR
%Longitude range is going from longUR to longLL

i = 1;
for i=i:262792
   if (NOAAlatlongdata(i,3) > latUR) && (NOAAlatlongdata(i,3) <latLL) &&     (NOAAlatlongdata(i,4) > (longUR)) && (NOAAlatlongdata(i,4) <(longLL))
   NOAAlatlongdata(i,1) = [];
   NOAAlatlongdata(i,2) = [];
   NOAAlatlongdata(i,3) = [];
   NOAAlatlongdata(i,4) = [];
   end
end
```

I've also tried to use methods of logical indexing, but I couldn't get more than one column considered at a time with the logical indexing, and I could only ever put one comparative operator >,<, <=, >=, in the logical indexing, which proved to be unhelpful.

I've also tried using logical indexing for just value ranges across the whole vector, but you'd quickly see that doing that will get rid of just values in one column and the first and second columns would be included in that. Those columns will need to stay, but not be considered in the conditionals.

If I can make this question more directed or clarify something, please let me know, as I'll be checking this regularly.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be done as follows

```
filter = NOAAlatlongdata(:,3) < latLL | NOAAlatlongdata(:,3) > latUR |...
         -NOAAlatlongdata(:,4) < longLL | -NOAAlatlongdata(:,4) > longUR;

NOAAlatlongdata(filter,:) = [];
```

Basically you create a logical index for the rows, and delete every row that is selected by the filter.

EDIT: Sorry, I just copied the logic you had in your example. I've changed it to exclude values that don't fall in the box you stated. Basically swap `&` for `|`.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Here is a ".mat" file with the data vector in question.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tsri4o2a19vcwhz/NOAAlatlongdata.mat

I ended up getting a <262792x1 logical> which were all zeros

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do is going to work. Can I just confirm that you want to exclude all the values where `lat > latUR`, `lat < latLL`, `long > longUR` and `long < longLL`?

Comment: Yes, that'd be correct. Which looks like it's being outlined in your code that your provided. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: In the file you've given me, all of the longitude values are positive. I've changed my answer to reflect this, and tested it with the data you gave me. The result was a `510x4` vector of data values.

Comment: I greatly apologize for not having that column with the correct sign, and I appreciate your patience in developing the answer. Really helps!! Thank you very much!